# Need to pass multiple values from a file as an argument

Tags: shell-script

File contains:

```
Firstname=ABC
Lastname=XYZ
Country=USA

Firstname=DEF
Lastname=UVW
Country=UK
```

Need to pass `Firstname`,`lastname` and `Country` to a function in the script as an argument and repeat the same for second set and so on.

Function Usage: If either of them missing, like `Country=` then it should exit if all 3 parameters has got values the should execute a command.

Comment: Thanks Egor Vasilyev, I wanted it to be in this format but could not get it

Comment: show your function definition and function usage

Comment: Function Usage: If either of them missing, like 'Country= ' then it should exit if all 3 parameters has got values the should execute a command.

Comment: You seem to imply that your file contains the 3 fields several times, do you want to run your function for each triplet ?

Comment: You are probably better off doing this in awk

Comment: @ValentinB. yes, that's what I wanna do along with a check if those fields have got values or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this ?

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}
     {
         split($1, a, "="); fname = a[2]; 
         split($2, b, "="); lname = b[2];
         split($3, c, "="); country = c[2];
         if (fname != "" && lname != "" && country != "") {
             command = "/path/to/your/script.sh "fname" "lname" "country;
             system(command);
         }
      }' input_file.txt
```

I tried it by replacing `/path/to/your/script` with `echo` and it did display the fields in the right order.

Note that if a field is missing for a given firstname, lastname, country combination, the command will not run for that particular combination, and it will directly skip to the next one.

If you want the awk command to exit with a non zero return code when encountering an empty field, and not try to run the command on the next combinations, try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}
     {
         split($1, a, "="); fname = a[2]; 
         split($2, b, "="); lname = b[2];
         split($3, c, "="); country = c[2];
         if (fname != "" && lname != "" && country != "") {
             command = "/path/to/your/script.sh "fname" "lname" "country;
             system(command);
         } else {
             print "error: empty field in input file !";
             exit 1
         }
      }' input_file.txt
```

Then you can test your return code in the shell variable `$?`. If it's not zero, a field is missing somewhere in your input files and all commands from that missing field and on were not run.

Comment: Thank you, But I am getting syntax error

 `split(,a,=); schema = a[2];
         ^ syntax error`
fatal: 0 is invalid as number of arguments for split

Comment: Can you show me the full command you are using ?

Comment: I tested my command on the input you provided and it worked, so I'm guessing that either you adapted it and made a syntax error, or the actual input that you have is different from the example you gave (e.g. it contains trailing or leading newlines).